# Is Disabling equivalent to deleting Google AppEngine API from the Project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-python27

I deployed API with a different name earlier. 
This API shows as a different API, under my API Manager Dashboard.

I disabled the old API for now. Does this have the same effect as deleting this API?